# redirect_uri not working in soundcloud

Tags: oauth, soundcloud, redirect

I had used the code of callback.html as show in "https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript" and saved
that callback.html file in my server

("http://www.openxcelltechnolabs.info/phonegap/sound/callback.html").

**Callback.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
 <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
</head>
<body onload="window.opener(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1);">
<b style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a      few seconds</b>
</body>
</html>
```

**here is my details**

```
client_id: "df20e6893cd18c616f9277adb284f0c8",
redirect_uri: "http://www.openxcelltechnolabs.info/phonegap/sound/callback.html"
```

When i run my app i am getting authentication window of sound cloud. But
after that when i click connect after entering my credentials it shows "This popup should automatically close in a few seconds" but its not getting closed.

And i had also add url in app setting.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.